# An efficient way to store metadata in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, metadata

I have a Neo4j graph, nodes, relationship, properties, works just fine.
The only thing is, I need to add some humanly readable and understandable descriptions of the labels, relationship types.
Is there an efficient way to do it within Neo4j?
Don't want to add them to every single node.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

1. Use descriptive names for the labels and relationship types. This avoids the need for separate metadata, and is very convenient.
2. Create distinct `Metadata` nodes like this, where the `name` is the name of a label or type (assuming that names are unique), and `desc` is the description:

   ```
   (:Metadata {name: 'Foo', desc: '...'})
   ```

   Create an index on `:Metadata(name)` for efficient querying.

   When you need to see the metadata for a node, you can make a query like this:

   ```
   MATCH (f:Whatever {id: 123})
   MATCH (m:Metadata) WHERE m.name in LABELS(f)
   RETURN f, COLLECT(m) AS metadataList
   ```

   For a relationship:

   ```
   MATCH ()-[r:SOME_TYPE]->()
   MATCH (m:Metadata) WHERE m.name = TYPE(r)
   RETURN r, m
   ```